# Show that the space $S$ of real sequences that are $0$ after a certain rank is not complete with the uniform norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Show that the space $S$ of all real sequences that are $0$ after a certain rank is not complete with the uniform norm. Find a metric space $X$ such that $\bar{S} = X.$

I took the sequence $x_{k}^{n}=(1,1/2,1/3,\cdots ,1/n,0,0,\cdots)$ then for $n\geq m$ 
$$||x_{k}^{n}-x_{k}^{m}||_{\infty}\leq \frac{1}{m+1}\to 0$$ and so the sequence $\{x^{n}_{k}\}$ is Cauchy. However it is not convergent since the limit $x=(1,1/2,1/3,\cdots)$ does not belong to $S.$ So $S$ is not complete. Next, I am guessing that $X= l^{\infty},$ but I am not sure how to prove this. Any hints will be much appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

If $X=\ell^{\infty}$, then you would be able to approximate the element 
$$\bar{x}=(1,1,1,\dots) $$
with eventually vanishing sequences. This is clearly not true. So $X$ is a smaller space.

More generally the problem is represent by elements containing infinitely many elements larger than $\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Indeed, in this case, if $\left\{x^k\right\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\subset S$, we have
$$\|x^k-\bar{x}\|_{\infty}\geq \varepsilon $$
and so $x^k\not \to \bar{x}$. But these are precisely the elements $\bar{x}=(\bar{x}_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\bar{x}_n\neq 0$. So we might guess that
$$X=\left\{x=(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in \ell^{\infty}:\lim_{n\to +\infty}x_n=0\right\} $$
it remains to verify that indeed, each element $x\in X$ can be approximated by a sequence $\left\{x^k\right\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ elements in $S$, and this is easily done by truncating the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ at the $k$-th index.